# Search and import multiple words from txt file on Biopython

Tags: biopython, fasta

Well, I have a *FASTA* file which has some info about a protein in a .txt and I want to search for "string" that comes after a pattern and import it/write it to another txt. It comes like this:

```
>gi|1168222|sp|P46098.1|
....(text)...
>gi|74705987|sp|O95264.1|
....(text)...
```

And I want to get all the accession numbers (acc): `sp|**P46098**.1|` and then save them in another file in a column. There are different acc throughout the text and what I want is what comes after the `sp|` and before the `.` or if it doesn't have a `.` is what is before the next `|`.

Is there any easy way of doing this in **Biopython**?

Thanks

Comment: does it always start with P? or is that O think it too? is it always starting with a capital letter followed by an integer or a float (in the case of O it looks like a float)? most people here havent done bioinformatics for several years if at all

Comment: @Joran accession IDs can vary tremendously. `sp` is the SwissProt accession ID, which is what I assume the OP wants. Generally, the number(s) after the `.` are revisions, so I'm guessing s/he wants everything after  `sp|` to the first `.`. That's purely guesswork, and there are easier ways of doing this with [Biopython](http://biopython.org).

Comment: And one other thing - this information will only be on a line starting with `>`.

Comment: ahh I stand corrected one person knows a significant ammount about bioinformatics :P

Comment: yes, I'm actually a scientist in biotech R&D. I'm only a nerd in my spare time :)

Comment: Do you know a simple way to do it with biopython @MattDMo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer uses Biopython to the extent that it's possible to, then uses regular expressions for the rest (Biopython will get the id for you, but not the accession number alone):

```py
from Bio import SeqIO
import re

with open('output.txt', 'w') as outFile: # open for writing
    for i in SeqIO.parse('input.txt', 'fasta'): # parse as FASTA
        m = re.search('sp\|(.*)\|', i.id) # look for sp|.*| in the id
        if m:
            outFile.write(m.group(1).split('.')[0] + '\n') # take only what's before the first dot, if any
```

Just as a note to the uninitiated: `'w'` overwrites any previously existing file, while `'a'` appends to it instead.

Also note that just using the regular expression match itself on the entire text (without using Biopython to parse out the FASTA ids first) would return the exact same result.

Comment: Than you @leekaiinthesky, that was exacly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to be using [lookbehinds](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). To use the example from that link:

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search('(?<=abc)def', 'abcdef')
>>> m.group(0)
'def'
```

On each line, you'd put the pattern you want to match in the lookbehind (i.e. where the `abc` is), and the stuff you want to capture in the following bit (i.e. where the `def` is).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there's a problem with that. I don't know what is `def` since it varies over the text.